# Memory leak due to org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl hard to trace

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have this Spring boot microservice that I suspect has a memory issue but I am unable to trace the suspected class back to the service code. Here are some indicating pictures, Seems like a persistence layer issue but we're not using the SessionFactoryImpl class directly anywhere.

[Memory chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qvgd.png)

[Shortest paths to the accumulate points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxBoX.png)

[Accumulated objects by class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwpnZ.png)

Comment: What makes you think that you have a memory leak?

Comment: The main reason is the large number of these concurrentHashmap objects being created and also that our k8 pod memory for this service always goes up but never goes down and stabilizes even at low traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it consume about 40M and the total is about 100M?
If so, that's a pretty low number of a JVM app.
If it doesn't grow more, I wouldn't be worried about it.

You might have a look at number of resources available about this topic:

- [Possible Memory Leak due to org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823599/possible-memory-leak-due-to-org-hibernate-internal-sessionfactoryimpl)
- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1088908/
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8943
- https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-memory-management/32/2
- https://github.com/ow2-proactive/scheduling/issues/2870