# annotated entity manager null pointed exception

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, entitymanager

I am doing a small project using JPA. I need to insert the employee object. 
For that when I use the annotated entity manager I got the NullPointer exception.
But when I use the Normal EntityManager without using the annotation it is working fine.
Do I need to configure somewhere else other than persistence.xml to work this examle fine?

Please see the code below.

```
public class EmployeeDao implements IEmployeeDao{       

     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "timesheet")
    private EntityManager entityManager ;

    @Override
    public boolean createEmployee(IEmployee employee) { 

        this.entityManager.persist(employee);       

        return true;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="timesheet" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">       
        <class>com.timesheet.model.Employee</class>     
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/timesheet" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Could you add the code where the crash occurs and the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @Traroth It happens on: this.entityManager.persist(employee), because entityManager is not injected and is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injection of resources (in your case via use of *@PersistenceContext*) works only in container managed classes (like EJBs and Servlets). This explained with more details for example in Java EE specification v6, EE5.2.5.

What you can do:

- Modify your class so that it is managed class
- move injection of resources to managed class and pass it to
  EmployeeDao,
- use JNDI lookup as before

Comment: but here in this project I am not using any ejb or servlet. I will directly access the service. In that case, Can I configure spring to make this work?

Comment: Yes you can, for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421339/how-to-inject-jpa-entitymanager-using-spring is explained how to without extending JpaDaoSupport. I would probably go for JNDI lookup, if Spring is not otherwise used in project. But that's just matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the annotation `javax.ejb.Stateless` for your `EmployeeDao` and `IEmployeeDao` classes. Entitymanager is a no-interface an Enterprise Java Bean injected in your client.

The client must be either a web component or another enterpise bean. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html) for further details about how to use EJBs.

In other words, using the `Stateless` annotation, the web container will take care of the lifecycle of your `EmployeeDao` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use transaction type of JTA instead of RESOURCE_LOCAL. You can acquire the EntityManager instance if and only if the program is running in app server and transaction type is JTA.

Answer (score 0):

So above all answers lead to summarise that :

- Injection of resources through annotation will work on container managed classes (e.g EJB, Servlet).
- Injection of resources can be done except annotation (e.g @PersistenceContext) on a simple JPA project ( a project which hasn't container managed classes ). Following code snippet give you lucid view :

  ```
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
  ```

Thanks to all for sharing knowledge.