# Override EntityManager.remove() in Spring Roo

Tags: hibernate, spring-roo, hibernate-entitymanager

I would like to override the `EntityManager.remove()` method for certain entities so that I can set an `active` boolean attribute to `false` rather than remove the object from the database entirely. This can be seen as a soft delete.

The remove method in the `Entity_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj` file for my class (called `Entity`, used as a superclass) looks like:

```
@Transactional
public void remove() {
    if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
    if (this.entityManager.contains(this)) {
        this.entityManager.remove(this);
    } else {
        Entity attached = Entity.findEntity(this.id);
        this.entityManager.remove(attached);
    }
}
```

I've found the definition of which `EntityManagerFactory` to use in `META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Would it be possible to subclass `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and provide my own `EntityManager` for a certain class, or is there a better way?

I've also noticed the use of `@PersistenceContext` to declare an attribute for the EntityManager:

```
@PersistenceContext
transient EntityManager Entity.entityManager;
```

But I suspect this is merely to store the EntityManager object and not to specify which implementation class to use (since EntityManager is an interface).

**EDIT:** The answer may lie in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421339/how-to-inject-jpa-entitymanager-using-spring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

**1. Push-in refactor the `remove()` method**

Instead of going all the way to change the entityManager, you can push-in refactor the `remove()` method to your entity class and set the `active` value to be `false` within the method and call `merge()`.

Also note that you would need to modify the finders and most other methods to filter the entities which are set to be `active=false`.

**2. Spring Roo Behaviors Add-on `@RooSoftDelete` annotation**

You can also use the following Spring Roo addon which enables a soft delete.

https://redmine.finalconcept.com.au/projects/final-concept-spring-roo-behaviours/wiki/Soft-delete-annoation

It lets you add a new annotation named `@RooSoftDelete` which takes care of soft deletion.

*Apart from the above, you can also write a custom entity manager factory that would take care of all as well.*

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, for your first method, I've already done this by moving the `Entity.remove()` method from the aspect into my `Entity` class, but this doesn't cascade the remove() (since I'm no longer using the entity manager I presume).