# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to resolve named mapping-file [hibernate.hbm.xml]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to add an hibernate mapping resource file to spring context. I didn't know how can I do this stuff?

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="myEmf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ProjectManagerDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ads" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ProjectManagerDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project-management" />
        <property name="username" value="usera" />
        <property name="password" value="userausera" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="jaxbMarshallerBean"> -->
    <!-- <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.ads.configs.AppConfig" /> -->
    <!-- </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller> -->


    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.ads.dao"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="myEmf" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ads.*" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>
```

I had founded a solution with Session factory but it wasn't working with my project as I'm using entity manager factory.

**UPDATED:** my new problem is that  javax.persistence.PersistenceException is occured 
 this is so my stack trace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEmf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to resolve named mapping-file [hibernate.hbm.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to resolve named mapping-file [hibernate.hbm.xml]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1221)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildMappingFileDescriptor(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildDeploymentResources(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
```

Comment: It will be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421339/how-to-inject-jpa-entitymanager-using-spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had changed the location of the file to src/main/resources then the problem  was solved.

Answer (score 0):

To your `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` bean add following proprety

```
<property name="mappingResources">
            <value>com/your/package/resources/*.hbm.xml</value>
        </property>
```

Comment: I tried with three manner but an exception is occured every time
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to resolve named mapping-file

Comment: Can you share the detailed stacktrace?

Comment: Where is your mapping file located in the project structure?

Comment: /WEB-INF/hibernate.hbm.xml  i tried to change the value of mappingResources attrtibute to /WEB-INF/hibernate.hbm.xml but the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your mapping files orm.xml if using JPA or hbm.xml if using hibernate are not in the deployment archive or they are at the wrong place or wrongly named at persistence.xml file or file name itself.

Because of these possible reasons your container or run-time can't find needed files that are declared at persistence.xml file.

Mapping files should be under META-INF or WEB-INF depending on deployment archive type.

At persistence.xml declaring like this for JPA:

/META-INF/jpa/Entity-orm.xml

would solve the possible directory related problems.

Assuming that Entity-orm.xml file is under /META-INF/jpa/ directory.