# How to inject EntityManager in Java SE using @PersistenceContext (EclipseLink)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager, persistence.xml

I have a client-server application that I made for a project at my university and I'm having problems with the database-JPA Cache synchronization. I'm using an application-managed EntityManager about which I found out from other posts that it's really hard to use because you always have to be careful to open and to close it.

The best solution which I found to this problem is to use a container-managed EntityManager, initialized using the @PersitenceContext annotation and this way I wouldn't have to worry about the EM opening and closing anymore.

So my real question is, how the injection of an EntityManager in Java SE using EclipseLink JPA is done, because I never passed the NullPointerException. I will attach some printscreens of an example of this operation and the way I think it should be done.

For my project I'm using jdk 1.8, basic jpa configuration(2.1) and EclipseLink 2.5.x as platform. On the DB side I'm using MySql-Server and no application server( this one has to be developed by me).

The persistence.xml file

[image]

The 2 classes which contain the example:
https://gyazo.com/a7b1a372875a259096dc220653cd5bcd

Comment: As Laszlo has said, you can only use a "container-managed EntityManager" if you have a "container". "Container" is a name for a framework like a Java EE server or Spring. The thing to remember about _all_ Java annotations is that they are just metadata with no behaviour. Some other code needs to read the annotation and then act on it: the "container".

Comment: (By the way, when you post code, please post the actual code, not screenshots. Use the code markup to get proper indentation and coloring.)

Comment: you can also start a cdi container yourself and without spring : https://deltaspike.apache.org/

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the container managed persistence according to the used technologies listed by you because you do not have a container which could handle the injection. My understanding is that you are not in a JEE application server therefore you do not have an EJB container.

If you want to use JPA in a standalone application you can do 2 things:

1. Forget the injection and use the application managed persistence.
2. Use a spring container and you can still inject: [How to inject JPA EntityManager using spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421339/how-to-inject-jpa-entitymanager-using-spring)