# Dynamic where JPA Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have an Table and Pojo in my Spring Boot application like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attendance_summary")
public class AttendanceSummary implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "attendance_summary_id_seq",
    sequenceName = "attendance_summary_id_seq",
    allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator = "attendance_summary_id_seq")
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
  public Integer id;

  @Column(name = "emp_id", nullable = false)
  public Integer empId;

  @Column(name = "designation_id")
  public Integer designationId;

  @Column(name = "designation_category_id")
  public Integer designationCategoryId;

  @Column(name = "department_id")
  public Integer departmentId;

  ......
}
```

Now I want have dynamic inputs for these fields. Meaning user might select 
a list of empIds, designationIds.... or any combinations of them or even none of them.
If they select none of the fields I need to return all the rows from the table in the database.

But in jpa when we write methods in repository we have to specify the field names like

```
public interface AttendanceSummaryRepository extends JpaRepository<Integer,AttendanceSummary>{
     List<AttendanceSummary> findByEmpIdAndDesignationId....(List<Integer> empIdList,List<Integer> designationIdList ... );
}
```

Which means if any of these parameters are null I will get an error or an exception and as a result I will miss some data.

where as in PHP or some other language like that I can just check the value of the desired filters and just dynamically add a where clause in the query.

```
query= "Select * from attendance_summary where ";
if(empIdList != null)
    query = query + " emp_id in empIdList "
if(designationIdList != null)
    query = query + " designation_id in designationIdList "
 .....
 //You get the idea.
```

Is there any way to do so with jpaDataMethods and if yes how. Any detailed explanation / link to resources are much appreciated.

Sorry for poor english and if I couldn't explain my problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Criteria API](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria). It allows you to create dynamic queries.

In your example, something similar to this could work:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<AttendanceSummary> query = cb.createQuery(AttendanceSummary.class);
Root<AttendanceSummary> root = query.from(AttendanceSummary.class);

List<Predicate> predList = new ArrayList<>();
if (empIdList != null) {
    predList.add(root.get('empId').in(empIdList));
}
if (designationIdList != null) {
    predList.add(root.get('designationId').in(designationIdList));
}
// ... You get the idea.

Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[predList.size()];
predList.toArray(predicates);

query.where(predicates);

return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: Sorry i am not experienced with spring boot much. What is the entity manager ? Looks like you injected it here to use it. Could you point me to some resources so that I can learn more about it?

Comment: The entity manager is able to access your entities like AttendanceSummary and can create SQL queries for you.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421339/how-to-inject-jpa-entitymanager-using-spring) shows you how to inject the entity manager with spring.

Comment: I think i have some problems in my usage of entity manager. I created the repository and its according implementation following this guide.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries
[link]I used above logic for constructing my queries. Sadly my code is getting a null pointer on the line 

CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

I turned on debug and saw my entityManager is null. Inspecting the issue and will let you know

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using `@Query` annotation. Please refer spring [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) for more details.

```
@Query(value = "from attendance_summary where (emp_id in (?1) or ?1 is null) and (designation_id in (?2) or ?2 is null)" )
```

## Query Detail:

```
SELECT * #implicit so removed
FROM   attendance_summary 
WHERE  ( emp_id IN (?1) #true when IDs are not null, thus apply filter
          OR ?1 IS NULL #true when user input null, return all rows ) 
       AND ( designation_id IN (?2) #true when IDs are not null, thus apply filter
              OR ?2 IS NULL #true user input null, return all rows)
```

[Example Project](https://github.com/amithkumarg/restapi-springboot-jpa) on github with spring-boot, jpa & h2. Look for `SchoolController` & `SchoolRepo` classes, applying the same logic, the endpoints `\school` will filter the result for input Ids & `\allschool` will return everything as input is null.

Comment: I only listed 2/3 fields here for example. In reality there are more fields. So if I do it this way, I have to handle a huge number of cases ( since the user can select any number of fields for the search. Eg: they selected emp_id and designation_id but not department id. Or department_id and designation_id and not any other.) Also I am told that the value inside @Query needs to be static. So I can't chain logic according to input. Might there be a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I changed the query to achieve the desired result, so you don't have to make multiple method signatures.

Comment: The db field values will never be null. If the user input for any field is null, I would have to exclude it from the search parameters. So this query won't work.

Comment: You didn't try the solution nor paid close attention to the query, I am not comparing the DB field to be null but the input itself. Added explanation to the query, so you will understand how its handling null filter

Comment: I tried the query. Got this exception

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

Comment: There was syntax error in `IN` clause, but logically it works. I corrected the answer & also added example to refer in my github project. Hopefully that helps.